# Allow more than one person signed into an account in PHP

Tags: php

Hey guys I am wondering if their is any way to have multiple accounts signed in at once for a user account.  I have a MySQL database and from that the PHP creates the session so I know it has to do with manipulating the session or something.  So my question is how can I have someone logged into one account and have another person on another computer sign into same account without the other being kicked off.

David

EDIT:

So on each page there are functions that do certain task for the user and my boss was on a meeting showing someone something and they were both signed into the same account from different computers and she was showing the guys some stuff and he kept getting kicked off.....is it because I have the

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    header("location:./mainlogin.php");
    exit;
}
```

on each page?

Comment: I think it is possible, for two people to log-in with the same account on two different browsers, regardless of talk about SESSIONS.

Comment: php couldn't care less how many people are "logged in". it has no concept of logins. If your code kicks out second logins, then that's your code doing it... no php. Since you've shown no code at all, the best answer you'll get is "sure, you can allow it".

Comment: Why is this being voted down?  Its a serious question I have.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've specifically put code in place to prevent it, this is going to be the default behaviour of sessions. Both users would have an open session for the same user.

Comment: So I should be fine?  for some reason though it was not working. The user just keeps getting kicked off.

Comment: Figure out why, then. If that's happening, it's something in your code, which we don't have.

Comment: Your edit shows very little of the involved code. If you didn't write in a "kick out the other user with this username" code, something else is going on.

Comment: Ya I never did write anything like that, I could be unsetting the variable someplace :(